# Java String pool Storage error

Tags: java, string

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        String a= "hello";
        String ab= a +"John";
        String abc = "helloJohn";
        System.out.println(ab==abc);

    }
}
```

> It prints `ab==abc` **false**. Shouldnt it be true..??

Comment: you need to study more about == and equal method.

Comment: you new guys should google before posting the question.

Comment: I think his point is not comparing the value, he is rather asking why `abc` is not the same reference as `ab`! Since I cannot post an answer I'll explain it here: Because Strings are immutable, when using `+` operator to concatenate two strings, a new String is created. That's why the comparing the reference (using `==`) returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use for `String` `equals`/`equalsIgnoreCase`. `'=='` compares objects, **NOT VALUES**. Because when you make `String a = "aa"` means you create new object.(like `new String("aa")`). In java there're `equals`() and `hashCode()` methods inherited from `Object` class, but you may override them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourStringVar.equals(anotherString)` to check if they contain the same sequence of character, use `==` to check if they refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In java, String is an object, so two String-objects which have same content will not be equal (because those are different objects), hence abc == ab is not true.
But there are methods to compare the contents of String objects. These are:

```
abc.equals(ab)
```

or

```
abc.compareTo(ab) == 0
```